# Make base_url relative in Drupal7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to make the base_url relative in Drupal 7. So it won't point to http://example.org/preview but to /preview.

How can I do that? Or how can I point the internal links all relative

//edit: I'm talking about all links in the finished html-source-code, what the browser gets to read.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way to do this in one swoop, but usually I would use code like this:

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
drupal_add_css($path . '/css/mymodulestyle.css', 'file');
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this because I was making a static copy of a site using httrack to run from a flash drive.

The only simple way of making links relative site-wide ( including css and js calls ) was to set

```
$base_url = '';
```

in setting.php

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by using [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function which simply can be used as the following Example :

```
echo url('preview', array('absolute' => TRUE)) ;
```

this example will link to http://example.com/preview

Comment: Sorry, You mean the $base_url variable ?

Comment: If so , please try to change the value of base_url in your settings.php file , Another solution is to use http://drupal.org/project/pathologic module , is that what you mean ?

Comment: I mean to have instead of the complete url for css and js files a relative one.

So instead of http://example.org/etc- I only want to have /etc-

And yes I meant the variable, sorry - but I can't change $base_url to "/preview" or an empty string - it results in a not working page.

Comment: I think ur Question need more Clarification, are you want create a relative path in a development (are you asking for how to make it programatically), or you want to change all your path links to be raltive...etc please explain more,thanks

Comment: I made it quick and dirty: str_replace('http://example.org', '', $styles); - in the html.tpl.php (and also for scripts)

Comment: i think its better to use `preg_replace()` function to modify the text 
try to do something like this 
`preg_replace('/([wW]{3,3}\.|)[A-Za-z0-9]+?\.(se|com|ru)/', ' ', $string) ;`  where $string is the string that you want to strip the site name from

Comment: and u can use `parse_url` function as the following parse_url($base_url, PHP_URL_PATH) which return the relative url , check this http://php.net/parse_url